Calendar Picker with Navigation of Month, Year using HTML, CSS and JS
I would like to create calendar component as shown in image with navigation on click of header of the calendar.
Expected 
i am able to implement one part of it
<!-- Implemented for date picker -->
Code pen example of current implementation
now seeking help for navigation to Year and  Decade on click of header of the calendar
if click on Apr 2024, then 2024 year and months, if i click again decade list should be displayed
expected result [ Only Functionality not look and feel ]
example
Thanks for support in advance


             

